# Clickable div without element inside

Tags: javascript

I've a code:

```
<div class="one" onclick="alert(1)">
<div class="two" onclick="alert(2)"></div>
</div>
```

When I click on the div with class "two" I get two alerts. But I only need one. How can I do it?

Help please

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5aHU/)

Comment: You need to stop events triggered from within `<div>` bubbling up through the DOM. Also, it's 2013, avoid intrusive event handlers.

Comment: @BenM and what is supposed to use instead onclick?

Comment: show your css here too, you are having this problem because one div is on top of the other

Comment: @Sionnach733 no, that's not the cause.

Comment: @BenM what is the cause then? an alert(2) is displayed followed by alert(1) when the red box is clicked.

Comment: It's nothing to do with their positioning. As I already explained, it's caused by the event from `div.two` bubbling up the DOM. If you stop propagation, the issue is gone.

Comment: @BenM ok but why addEventListener is better onclick? I'm a beginner..

Comment: @user3073240 because wherever possible, JavaScript should be uncoupled from the view.

Answer (score 3):

stopPropagation will prevent the event from bubbling after it's been handled by div 'two'

```
<div class="one" onclick="alert(1)">
<div class="two" onclick="event.stopPropagation();alert(2)"></div>
</div>
```

though javascript embedded in HTML is ugly and should be avoided

Comment: what is it mean to be avoided? using events?

Comment: you have javascript embedded directly in HTML, this is an out dated way of handling events which has been deprecated in favour of [addEventListener](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html). Having code in HTML markup makes it hard to read as it is scattered around, it's also easier to add and remove event handlers when necessary using addEventListener/removeEventListener